# Css animation on background image is not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

Please tell transition/animation properties for chrome differs ? or Am I doing something wrong?

: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aradhayaKansal/7cgkj/)

```
 @-webkit-keyframes water 
{ 0% {background-position: 0 0;}
100% {background-position: 100000% 0;}
}
@keyframes water {  
0% {background-position: 0 0;}
100% {background-position: 100000% 0;}
}
```

Solved :  http://jsfiddle.net/aradhayaKansal/7cgkj/3/ ! thanks to Mr. Alien

Comment: In addition to Mr.Alien's fix, your `linear-gradient` syntax is horribly outdated: http://jsfiddle.net/7cgkj/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting `-webkit-animation: water 5000s linear infinite;` as well as `-webkit-animation: flow 5000s linear infinite;` for `webkit` as still, chrome requires them, you can check [this](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) out

[image]

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cgkj/1/)

```
#waterfall { 
  /* Other properties */
  -webkit-animation: flow 5000s linear infinite; /* <--- Here */
  animation: flow 3s forwards linear normal;
}
```

And

```
#water {
  /* Other properties */
  -webkit-animation: water 5000s linear infinite; /* <---- here */
  animation: water 5000s linear infinite;
}
```

> Note: Just make sure you use `-moz-` as well...